How to Make a Scrollable Basic TextField text in Jetpack Compose with Cursor Movement?
I'm working on a Jetpack Compose application and I need to create a scrollable TextField that allows users to input long text. However, I want to allow users to scroll text by cursor to reach end or start of text and scrolls through the text.


@Composable
fun AppScreen() {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Blue), shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            singleLine = true,
            value = value,
            onValueChange = { newText ->
                value = newText

            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(8.dp))
    }
}



Hello @Sathosh, have you tested below answer, does it fulfill your use case? If it does, please consider marking it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer. Thank you!

Yes i tested, but it is not worked. Some times the when i scroll to end the cursor goes after few characters from end but not scrolled. Using                 .horizontalScroll(scrollState) for basic textfield is not best practice because basic textfield has its own scroll state already i think. So we should use  fun BasicTextField(
state: TextFieldState,
modifier: Modifier = Modifier, this version i think. It has scroll state param to manage scrolling behaviour in control. I haven't tried, if you know update the code. And i will do also once tried.

This is a tricky one. It seems that there is no easy way to get the index of the first currently visible character in the BasicTextField, so you need to perform some calculations based on the bounds of the BasicTextField, cursor position, and scroll position.
What we need to do:

make the BasicTextField scrollable by applying the horizontalScroll Modifier
use the onTextLayout callback to obtain the current pixel coordinates of the cursor within the BasicTextField
observe the value of the ScrollState to calculate how close the cursor currenly is to the left or right bounds of the BasicTextField

Please try the following code:
@Composable
fun AppScreen() {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    // autoScrollThreshold: distance of cursor to left or right edge when auto scrolling should start
    val autoScrollThreshold = remember { 50 }  // adjust as needed
    val innerPadding = with(LocalDensity.current) { 16.dp.toPx() }
    var textFieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
    var textLayoutResult by remember {
        mutableStateOf<TextLayoutResult?>(null)
    }
    val cursorCoordinates by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (value.text.isEmpty()) {
                Rect(0f,0f,0f,0f)
            } else {
                val targetIndex = value.selection.start.coerceIn(0, value.text.length - 1)
                textLayoutResult?.getCursorRect(targetIndex)
            }
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(value.selection) {
        val cursorStartDistance = (cursorCoordinates?.left ?: Float.MAX_VALUE) - scrollState.value
        if (cursorStartDistance < autoScrollThreshold) {
            scrollState.animateScrollBy(-40f)
        }
        val cursorEndDistance = scrollState.value + textFieldSize.width - innerPadding - (cursorCoordinates?.right ?: Float.MIN_VALUE);
        if (cursorEndDistance < autoScrollThreshold) {
            scrollState.animateScrollBy(40f)
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(0.75f)
            .padding(16.dp)
            .border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Blue), shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                textFieldSize = it.size
            }
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            singleLine = true,
            value = value,
            onValueChange = { newText ->
                value = newText
            },
            onTextLayout = {
                textLayoutResult = it
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(8.dp)
                .horizontalScroll(scrollState)
        )
    }
}

Output:

